# UInt8 from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uint

I need a clarification. I'm following a tutorial on **Hash sha256** in **Swift** and my app is in **Objective-C**. I have trouble translating this `UInt8` in Objective-C. What is the equivalent in Objective-C?

```
let rsa2048Asn1Header:[UInt8] = [
        0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
        0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00
    ]
```

I tried this but I'm not sure it's right I'd like to have confirmation

```
UInt8 rsa2048AsnlHeader[] = {
         0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
         0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes what you posted above would work if you're just looking to use a primitive array in Objective-C.

Another option would be to use `NSArray`, shown below:

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *rsa2048AsnlHeader = @[
    @0x30, @0x82, @0x01, @0x22, @0x30, @0x0d, @0x06, @0x09, @0x2a, @0x86, @0x48, @0x86,
    @0xf7, @0x0d, @0x01, @0x01, @0x01, @0x05, @0x00, @0x03, @0x82, @0x01, @0x0f, @0x00
];
```

To get the equivalent `UInt8` value from the `NSNumber` elements, use the `unsignedCharValue` property of the `NSNumber` class (which is equivalent to `uint8Value` in Swift).  For example:

```
for (NSNumber *value in rsa2048AsnlHeader) {
    UInt8 uint8Value = value.unsignedCharValue;
    // ...
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1409016-unsignedcharvalue?language=objc)

Comment: I understand ... I'm another help for the Swift equivalence of a method .. it's the first time I work with SHA256 and I'm trying to understand but we also understand the equivalent The C lens of Swift becomes a bit 'complicated. .. can I bother you further? this way you could also tell me my UInt8 implementation is correct

Comment: @kAiN Sure feel free to post another question and I can try to help you out.  In the meantime please kindly accept this answer if it solved your original problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure!.. I posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361681/sha256-swift-to-objective-c-equivalence.... I accept your answer for this question.. Thanks ryanecrist