# SHA256 Swift to Objective C equivalence

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdata, sha256

Hello everyone I'm working for the first time with SHA256 and I'm trying to follow a tutorial on this my problem is to write the equivalence in Objective C of SHA 256. I'm trying to understand the function that I show you below but I still have problems on how to find the equivalence in Objective C of this Swift function

```
let rsa2048Asn1Header:[UInt8] = [
        0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
        0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00
    ]

 private func sha256(data : Data) -> String {
        var keyWithHeader = Data(bytes: rsa2048Asn1Header)
        keyWithHeader.append(data)
        var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        keyWithHeader.withUnsafeBytes {
            _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(keyWithHeader.count), &hash)
        }
        return Data(hash).base64EncodedString()
    }
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+sha256)?

Comment: I tried to see many examples but I did not want to go wrong with the equivalent in Objective C of that function ... They look very different from each other

Comment: Try it out! If you get the sane result in Swift and ObjC you found the right solution. Actually Stackoverflow is not a code writing / code conversion service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with raw bytes in Objective-C is generally a little more straightforward than Swift.  An implementation like this should be equivalent.

```
#define RSA_2048_ASN1_HDR_LEN 24

- (NSString *)sha256:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableData *keyWithHeader = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:rsa2048Asn1Header length:RSA_2048_ASN1_HDR_LEN];
    [keyWithHeader appendData:data];
    UInt8 hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH] = { 0 };
    CC_SHA256(keyWithHeader.bytes, (CC_LONG) keyWithHeader.length, hash);
    return [[NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

Note that you'll also need to import the common crypto library into your Objective-C file as well:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```